# Apache Avro : UnresolvedUnionException when using union data type

Tags: java, apache, avro

I am using [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/gettingstartedjava.html) for object serialization.

I have one Avro schema for `School` object:

```
{"namespace": "com.my.model",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "School",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "sid",  "type": "int"},
     {"name": "size",  "type": "long"},
     {"name": "other", "type": ["null", "Teacher", "Student"]}
   ]
}
```

As you see above, the `"other"` field holds an **union data type**, it could be either `null` or a `Teacher` instance or a `Student` instance.

The **Teacher** object schema:

```
{"namespace": "com.my.model",
"type": "record",
"name": "Teacher",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "isMale", "type": "boolean"}
    ]
}
```

The **Student** object schema:

```
{"namespace": "com.my.model",
"type": "record",
"name": "Student",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "age", "type": "int"}
    ]
}
```

I compiled above schemas with Avro tool & Avro generated all the Java classes for me automatically.

Then, in my java program I am creating `School` instance in the following way:

```
School school = new School();
school.setSid(3);
school.setSize(2000);

//create a student object
Student student = new Student();
student.setAge(18);

//set student into school instance
school.setOther(student);
```

As you see above, the school instance's `other` field holds a student object. When I compile my code, however I got the **UnresolvedUnionException** . It complains about the **union data type** for the `other` field of `School` schema. Seems it can not resolve the `student` I set to `school` in my Java code. Why is this exception ? Stacktrace is:

```
org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"record","name":"Student","namespace":"com.my.model","fields":[{"name":"age","type":"long"}]},{"type":"record","name":"Teacher","namespace":"com.model","fields":[{"name":"isMale","type":"boolean"}]}]: false
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:561)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:144)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:106)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeArray(GenericDatumWriter.java:131)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:68)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:106)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can be mistaken, but I think Union type should contain only one non default value:

```
{
    "name": "other",
    "type": [
        "null",
        "Teacher",
        "Student"
    ]
}
```

should be:

```
{
    "name": "other",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "name": "Visitors",
            "symbols": [
                "Student",
                "Teacher"
            ],
            "type": "enum"
        }
    ]
}
```